# GetAdaptersInfo crashing

Tags: c++, winapi, crash, hwid

I'm currently trying to do some hardware generation for a friend of mine and I noticed that GetAdaptersInfo kinda behaves weirdly. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917(v=vs.85).aspx) pOutBufLen should be pointing to a variable holding the value of `sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO)` (640). But when I use that value it returns 111 (`ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW`) and sets outBufLen to 2560. When calling the function with outBufLen set to 2560 it just crashes.

Minimal reproduction code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Iphlpapi.h>

int main()
{
    IP_ADAPTER_INFO adapter_inf;
    unsigned long int outBufLen = sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO);

    GetAdaptersInfo(nullptr, &outBufLen); // returning 111 (ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) and setting outBufLen to 2560
    GetAdaptersInfo(&adapter_inf, &outBufLen); // crash during this call

    return 0;
}
```

Don't know if it matters but 64-bit Windows 8 here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
GetAdaptersInfo(nullptr, &outBufLen);
```

After this returns a value in `outBufLen` you are expected to pass a buffer of that length in the subsequent call. You do not do that, hence the runtime error.

You need to allocate the `pAdapterInfo` dynamically using the length returned in `outBufLen`.

```
ULONG outBufLen = 0;
if (GetAdaptersInfo(nullptr, &outBufLen) != ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW)
    // handle error
PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo = (PIP_ADAPTER_INFO) malloc(outBufLen);
if (GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, &outBufLen) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    // handle error
```

I've used `malloc` here, and a C style cast, but you might prefer to use `new` and a C++ style cast. I didn't do that through my own lack of familiarity.

Obviously you need to free the memory when you are finished with it.

Comment: Just casually hating myself after 3 hours of depression.  
Thank you.

Comment: So does that mean the IP_ADAPTER_INFO struct is smaller than the length returned by the first call?

Comment: @OtávioDécio Yes.

Comment: @OtávioDécio Yes indeed. A linked list is returned, in the buffer that you provide. `IP_ADAPTER_INFO` describes just a single item and contains a `next` pointer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ah, that makes a lot of sense.